# ¿Cómo controlar viñeta de una lista de forma vertical en una lista desordenada?

Tags: html, css

El problema es que la viñeta esta en la parte de abajo del texto quisiera subirla un poco para que se vea mas centrada, ¿Cómo podría lograr esto?:

[image: El problema es que la viñeta esta en la parte de abajo del texto quisiera subirla un poco para que se vea mas centrada, ¿Cómo podría lograr esto?]

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: square;
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.listas span{
  margin-left: -0.9em;
}
.listas {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="listas"><span>½ taza de cebolla picada</span></li>
  <li class="listas"><span>½ taza de pimiento verde picado</span></li>
  <li class="listas"><span>2 paquetes (10 onzas) de verduras mixtas para ensalada</span></li>
  <li class="listas"><span>4 fiambre de pollo en rodajas finas, picado</span></li>
  <li class="listas"><span>1 tomate picado</span></li>
  <li class="listas"><span>¼ de cucharadita de cebolla en polvo</span></li>
  <li class="listas"><span>3 chorritos de ajo en polvo</span></li>
  <li class="listas"><span>2 pizzas de sal y pimienta negra molida al gusto</span></li>
  <li class="listas"><span>3 cucharadas de aderezo para ensaladas con vinagreta balsámica</span></li>
</ul>
```

¿Cómo seria la forma de centrar la viñeta que se vea mejor siento que esta muy abajo y no se visualiza muy bien como seria la forma correcta de hacer esto?

Answer (score 0):

Hola como estas ? El problema esta en que tenes
list-style-position: inside, esto provoca que la viñeta se situe dentro de la linea.
Si no declaras eso por defecto list-style-position se encuentra en outside lo que hace que la viñeta se situe fuera de la linea, de esa manera vas a tener la viñeta centrada.
Te recomiendo que en el css elimines este estilo y ya vas a tener la viñeta centrada.